# Unexpected result using hair particles + interpolated children + Solidify (Blender 2.93.5)

Tags: particles, solidify-modifier

[image]

Hello,
I'm trying to follow along the tutorial here, making a towel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEpsN1-W-Qw

I didn't follow the exact steps when it came to the particle system, thinking it would be more efficient to use interpolated children than to crank the number of particles to 1 million...

So - that is what I did, and the result can be seen in the attached image, as no. 1.

I was pretty happy with that result, but since it is a single plane, there are only hair particles on one side.

The solution to this in the tutorial was to use Solidify - and checking the "use modifier stack" option in the particle system.

But that turned out weird as can be seen in no 2. Instead of spreading evenly it forms clumps - and looking at the other side it seems the patches match, i.e. where there are particles on the front there are none on the back and vice versa.

I then tried some other experiments to try and understand what is happening.

Instead of a plane, I applied the same particle system to a cube, and scaling it done in Y, getting the result in no 3. This is what I would have expected in no 2 as well, fewer particles since it needs to cover both sides, but still evenly distributed.

And then perhaps the most unexpected behavior - if I apply the scale on the cube in no 3 - we are back to the weird clumps.

So...a bug? Or am I misunderstanding something?
To be clear, all clumping parameters and such are left as default, all examples in the image use the same particle settings.

Edit:
I found one thing that affects the result - the thickness of the Solidify modifier. If the object is too thin, this behavior starts happening.
Does this mean that you can't use interpolated children on too thin objects?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is already reported bug.

Comment: Bug report https://developer.blender.org/T42884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered already to your self :)

Just few details ... They are distributed a cross each front/back surface similar to Cube, but ... thin emitter switched some hair particles to opposite direction ...

[image]

... a specific hair particle on front and back side goes in that area the same direction. So in "empty" areas they are still there, but under surface pointing in direction of opposite face (that's the glittering part in anim gif - Cone's bottom circle visible as Z-fight).

[image]
(10 hair particles with 1000 interpolated children)

[image]

So yeah ... seems like a bug (or limitation?), but there is almost zero chance for fix ... since particle system has a lot of small thing that are hard to fix and rather that new particle system is awaited. Or I can be wrong and there is some controller that I don't know about it ...

No4 is than expected result, because No3 is scaled in object mode. It means you changed dimension but not vertices distances that are calculated as before scale on Y axis (calculated from cube shape). *Applying Scale* make faces "real" and are calculated as short distanced = producing interpolation seen in No2.

[Related thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244038/2214)

Comment: Sidenote ... it is not a first time I was thinking if wouldn't be helpful to let blender display vertices in edit mode in Scale 1/1/1 to be clear for user how vertices are taken into calculation ... seems to me less confusing ... and it could solve many questions here based on issue generated by transformations in Object mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit more with potential workarounds...I think the one that gives me the best result so far is if you apply the Solidify modifier, and then duplicate the particle system so they are separate systems on the front and back part, then they don't affect each other...

It's not ideal though, since I was using shape keys and you can't apply the modifier to a mesh with shape keys...

But somehow keeping front and back particle systems separate is probably the only way, as I understand it.