# Interpolated children hair particles showing up inside mesh

Tags: particles, error, hair

I'm very new to blender and have been experimenting with the particle system for fur. I have this cat model and I've been trying to add fur to it, however for some reason there are some interpolated children that show up inside the mesh and I've had no luck figuring out why this is happening or how to prevent it. There's been similar questions posted in the past but I've not found anything recent for blender 2.9. The hair particles show inside even before any grooming.

I know the topology might not be the best, but I've tried to get it as clean as I can, I've recalculated the normals and check them with 'face orientation' everything on the outside is blue and everything inside is red. I've tried everything I can think of or find online, but for me nothing is working. I'm sure there is something I've missed that's causing this behaviour.

[image: 1]
(hair inside mesh)

When grooming, this is causing bald patches in the fur as large sections of fur are inside the mesh. This is particularly bad in the tail and legs.

[image: 2]
(bald patches)

I've been able to mitigate the effect a bit by using the add brush in particle edit mode, but it's difficult to make the fur even and consistent.

Any thoughts or advice as to how to fix this would be much appreciated. I've attached the blender file here. Thanks so much!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnfaysrb64pjsc5/lion%20mesh%20symetrised%20fur%20V1.blend?dl=0

Comment: can u tell us why you don't want or why it bothers you that they are inside the mesh? and maybe a screenshot of that would help us...

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the comment and sure thing, will add the info and screenshots.

Comment: OK it is a bug not considered as a bug :) https://developer.blender.org/T42884 , but check Lukas's answer for [possible workarround](https://developer.blender.org/T42884#275482) ... also your post is duplication of [this thread here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240957/2214)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is reported bug (aka TODO).

Comment: thanks for all the info vklidu, really appreciate it. apologies for the duplication of threads

Answer (score 2):

*Originally posted by developer* [Lukas Toenne](https://developer.blender.org/T42884#275482)

---

The problem is the way child particles are interpolated between parents, which does not work well with sparse sampling on thin geometry such as the ears and the throat area (which you modelled as a 2-sided tube). A child particle then often has to select parents from the opposite sides of the object, with diverging normals, which give it an unnatural direction.

Possible solutions/workarounds:

- Add more parents! This reduces cases where parents with conflicting directions are interpolated. Ideally the distance between parents should be less than the thickness of the geometry.
- Use "simple" instead of "interpolated" children. This not as smoothly distributed, so it may not be an option, but they avoid the interpolation pitfalls.
- At least for the throat area: remove the particles on the inside, assuming you don't want a furry throat anyway. This will make children only interpolate between parents on the actual surface.

In the future we may want to implement nicer surface-distance methods instead of using the current euclidian distance for interpolating (see e.g. http://peterwonka.net/Publications/pdfs/2009.EGSR.Cline.PoissonSamplingOnSurfaces.pdf). This should solve many currently problematic cases, but it's not going to happen with the current particle system.